# Sliding processing time window computes inconsistent results

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Flink, I am reading a file using `readTextFile` and applying `SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(60), Time.milliseconds(60))` of 60 msec with slide of 60 msec on it. On windowed stream I am calculating the mean of the second filed of the tuple. My text file contains 1100 lines and each line is tuple (String, Integer). I have set the parallelism to 1 and keyed the messages on first field of the tuple.

When I run the code, each time I get different answers. I mean that it seems like, sometime it reads entire file and sometime it reads one first some lines of the file. Does it have some relation with window size of sliding amount? How this relation can be found out so that I can decide the size and sliding amount of window?

Comment: You can't expect consistent, repeatable results when working with processing time. In your case it's then simply a matter of how much of the file can be processed in 60msec, and that will vary depending on system load, etc. Sometimes it's able to handle the whole file, and sometimes it can't; that's normal. Take a look at http://data-artisans.com/how-apache-flink-enables-new-streaming-applications-part-1/ for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the comment of AlpineGizmo is correct. I'll add a few more details here.

Flink aligns time windows to the begin of epoch (`1970-01-01-00:00:00`). This means that a window operator with a 1 hour window starts a new window with every new hour (i.e., at `00:00`, `01:00`, `02:00`, ...) and not with the first arriving record.

Processing time windows are evaluated based on the current time of the system. 
As said in the comment above, this means that the amount of data which can be processed depends on the processing resources (hardware, CPU/IO load, ...) of the machine that an operator runs on. Therefore, processing time window cannot produce reliable and consistent results.

I your case, both described effects might cause results which are inconsistent across jobs. Depending on when you start the job, the data will be assigned to different windows (if the first record arrives just before the first 60 msecs window is closed, only this element will be in the window). Depending on the IO load of the machine it might take more or less time to access and read the file.

If you want to have consistent results, you need to use event-time. In this case, the records are processed based on the time which is encoded in the data, i.e., the results depend on the data only and not on external effects such as the starting time of the job or the load of the processing machine.